# dispatchEvent KeyboardEvent typings issue

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

Im having a problem trying to trigger a keyup event for a backspace key press on a native element in my Angular unit tests.

If I try:

```
debugElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {code: 'Backspace'}));
```

I get a TypeError:

```
TypeError: KeyboardEventConstructor is not a constructor (evaluating 'new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { code: 'Backspace' })')
```

I dont get any errors in my editor (VSCode), and if I following the type definitions through (to the DOM APIs typings file), the constructor for a KeyboardEvent is:

```
new(typeArg: string, eventInitDict?: KeyboardEventInit): KeyboardEvent;
```

and the second arg takes an interface defined as follows:

```
interface KeyboardEventInit extends EventModifierInit {
    code?: string;
    key?: string;
    location?: number;
    repeat?: boolean;
}
```

I'm not sure where I am going wrong here, can anyone assist?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

(assuming you are using ng-cli transpiling) Seems to work fine, here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-template-driven-test-example-keyboardevent)

As it's typings error there it could likely either be an incompatible version of the lib.dom.d.ts or you somehow have the setup when compiling/transpiling TS incorrectly.

(version incompatibilities with Angular might occur with following suggestion)

Try first with either with updating typings with

> npm install typescript@latest

or simply check your package.json "typescript": "~2.7.2" that it's using an up to date version and configured according to your Angular version.